# Pyspark: Need to assign Value to specific index using for loop

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have Data Frame and wanted to:

i) update some value at specific index only in a column

ii) update value from one column to another column at specific index (corresponding index)

I do not want to use `df.with_column(.....)` to update the values as doing some calculation and then updating the value in each iteration.
I have given below the sample code but it is not working as expected.

```
df = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2], [3, 4],[1,6],[7,8],[0,1],[0,1],[0,2]], schema=["a", "b"])
val = 2
for i in df.collect():
    if(i['a'] == 0):
        i["a"] = val
    else:
        i['a'] = i['b']
```

[image]

Expected output :
the highlighted zeros in **'col A'** should get updated with **'2'** and if not equals zeros it should get updated with corresponding values from **'col B'**

I have tried all the ways but not able to get the expected output
Please help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4],[1,6],[7,8],[0,1],[0,1],[0,2]], schema=["a", "b"])

val = 2

df.withColumn("a", when(col("a") == 0, val).otherwise(col("b"))).show()
```

Output

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  2|  2|
|  4|  4|
|  6|  6|
|  8|  8|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  2|
+---+---+
```